# how to change JLabel color

Tags: java, swingutilities, awr

i have problem to change JLabel color. i am using three `JLabel` variables . i am putting mouse event on this `JLabel` variables. i run the and both are changes color when i am entring mouse on `JLabels`. i whis is that, at the time one `JLabel` change the color when I am entering the mouse on `JLabel` variable.

please solve this problem.

```
    entry.addMouseListener(this);
    entry.setOpaque(true);
    profile.addMouseListener(this);
    profile.setOpaque(true);

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mc)
    {


    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) 
    {
        entry.setBackground(color);
        profile.setBackground(color);
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) 
    {

    entry.setBackground(Color.white);
    profile.setBackground(Color.white);

   }
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mp) 
   {

   }
   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mr)
   {

   }
```

Comment: What is your question? I dont understand.Btw isnt setForeground(color ) what you want? that change labels font color.

Comment: Are you asking why _both_ labels change color when you move the mouse over just _one_ of them? In this case, try `me.getSource().setBackground(...)`.

Comment: @tobias_k: preferably `getComponent()` instead of `getSource()` as otherwise you need a type-cast. But I think you nailed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are asking... I assume that your problem is that you have *two* labels and when you enter the mouse into one of them you want just *that* label to have a red background, not both.

To do so, you can get the label that triggered the mouse event using `e.getComponent()` and then set the background for that label only. Also, you might want to use `setBackground(null)` to reset the background color, since the background of the underlying frame might not always be white. Finally, you can use the `MouseAdapter` class instead of the `MouseListener`, providing defaults (no-op) for all those other method you do not need.

```
MouseListener ma = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        e.getComponent().setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        e.getComponent().setBackground(null);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is the method `setBackground()`, change on `setForeground()`:

```
entry.addMouseListener(this);
entry.setOpaque(true);
profile.addMouseListener(this);
profile.setOpaque(true);

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mc)
{}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) 
{
    entry.setForeground(Color.red);
    profile.setForeground(Color.red);
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) 
{
    entry.setForeground(Color.white);
    profile.setForeground(Color.white);
}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mp) 
{}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mr)
{}
```